# How often do Azure AD key rolls occur?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm vetting Azure AD's Open ID Connect for securing a Web API. I came across a vague description of the frequency of how often Azure AD performs key rolls.

Azure AD documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#overview-of-signing-keys-in-azure-ad

Specifically:

> For security purposes, Azure AD’s signing key rolls on a periodic basis

I can't find anywhere in the documentation the actual interval; or is this info meant to be hidden away from devs/users?

Comment: Hi Jeff, you shall not stick to any fixed period. A lot of things can cause a key rollover. That's why you have the .well-known configuration data which points you to the correct keys. Also, the OIDC standard does not enforce fixed period for key roll over. Last, but not least, this is not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @astaykov Apologies, I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere else, but I really appreciate you answering. If I can ask a follow-up, do you happen to know a max duration for keys?

Comment: Go and read [the specs](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RotateSigKeys). If there is nothing about duration, then there is nothing about duration. Period.

Comment: There is nothing about duration yet an estimation of how often Microsoft usually does it de-facto would help. I appreciate there are edge cases when compromised keys are revoked instantly but apart from that, how often a planned rollover happens? Once a day? Once a year?

Comment: Is there some sort of rate limiting on this JWK endpoint? @astaykov like how many requests can be done in a certain timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

Since the OAuth2.0 protocol specification doesn’t requires a specific periodic lapse of time we should not expect Azure AD to implement the feature due to it can be taken as a compromise

Instead you have the freedom to fix your own periodic refresh of signing process by using the  [Token Signing Key Scripts](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-powershell-tokenkey)

I hope that helps, good luck!